# Could El Hierro eruption cause a mega-tsunami?

Tags: geology, natural-disasters

Could an eruption of El Hierro in the Canary Islands lead to a megatsunami that would threaten the eastern coast of the United States or elsewhere?

Comment: Where's the notable claim?

Comment: http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/science/nature/3963563.stm covers both sides of the argument to some degree. Though that is from 2004 and not addressing El Hierro specifically.

Answer (score 1):

> Islands of volcanic origin, such as the Canaries, have an especially
>   large potential for triggering a tsunami. That the Canaries constitute
>   a danger was shown 300 000 years ago when a part of the island El
>   Hierro slid into the sea, triggering a mega-tsunami which carried
>   rocks as high as a house for many hundreds of metres into the interior
>   of the east coast of what is today the USA. The danger of a similar
>   island collapse is seen by scientists particularly at the island of La
>   Palma in the Canaries. Here, following a volcanic eruption in 1949
>   almost half of the mountain range of 20 km moved westwards towards the
>   sea, leaving a large tear in the volcanic basalt. In the event of a
>   fresh eruption, a huge part of the volcano could loosen itself due to
>   differences in the types of rock and diverse water deposits within the
>   now active volcano. As a result, the densely populated east coast of
>   America would be massively threatened. According to a computer
>   simulation by Stephen N. Ward and Simon Day, a tsunami (purple-red on
>   the graphics) would rush across the Atlantic if the slopes of the
>   Cumbre Vieja.volcano were to collapse into the sea.

and further

> Knowing that the recent major tsunami in Japan traveled 4.000 miles
>   across the Pacific to produce an approximate 3 foot tsunami on some
>   areas of the US west coast, the approximate ratio was 10:1 as the wave
>   reached the US coastline. There are many factors that are at work to
>   determine tsunami height, and this is highly over-simplifying the
>   formula – the point is that if this were to be a similar case on the
>   US east coast, which is 3,000 miles from the Canary Islands, the
>   tsunami height could be 30 to 40 feet – while some suggest even
>   higher.

[Ref 1](http://www.tsunami-alarm-system.com/en/phenomenon-tsunami/occurrences-atlantic-ocean.html) and [Second Ref.](http://modernsurvivalblog.com/volcano/300-foot-tsunami-and-east-coast-destruction/)

There are voices talking about an 'over-hyped' thread:

> But researchers taking part in a three-week research cruise aboard
>   Southampton Oceanography Centre's research ship, the RRS Charles
>   Darwin, say the threat is far lower than previous warnings would
>   suggest.
>
> Doug Masson, who has been researching Canary Islands landslides for 20
>   years, says the models are a worst-case scenario.
>   [Ref3](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/science/nature/3963563.stm)

Comment: You should expand this post with all the opposing views considering this to be extremely unlikely.

Comment: well, it COULD happen. Of course chances of it happening are miniscule, especially on the timescale of a human lifetime.

Comment: I am interested in the opposing arguments as well. Also, the people/institutes for vs against might be useful.

Comment: It seem to be difficult to find credible source for opposing arguments. It will be a matter of (perhaps long) time, but likely to happen. As a view from the other side : http://www.lapalma-tsunami.com/